# In Master Of Orion, is there a relocate functionality?

Tags: master-of-orion-2016

In Master Of Orion I at least, there was a RELOC functionality that allowed you to send all produced ship of one system to another.
Is there a similar functionality in released Master Of Orion 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not that I have ever seen.

As each ship is created, you need to tell it where to go. It becomes a little tedious later in the game, when you are possibly cranking out tons of ships to fight off the Meklar armadas.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are the Meklar, you are cranking out the armadas. Not making it better.